# Stepcounter in background in ionic project

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I've been searching the internet for solutions for a while now, without success. I need a cordova plugin, or any kind of way, to get the steps that the phone's holder took. I found ionic-native's pedometer, but it only counts the steps when the application is open, or at least running, and it also restarts the counting on app close.

I also found the Health plugin, but to make it work on an android device, it seems like a lot of effort (e.g. the user needs to download the Google Fitness application, log into it etc).

Does anyone have a clear solution for counting the steps even when the ionic application is not running? (I need it on both iOS and android, but it's not a problem if I need to implement it in two ways, different way for each.)

Thank you in advance,
a very disappointed googler. :/

Comment: hey Hienz,  please take me through how to achieve the step counter functionality in ionic,

Comment: Hello. I was using at last the ionic cordova Health plugin, so I gathered the health informations from the Google Fitness & iOS Health Kit applications. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/health/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proves to be a very difficult problem for ionic. 
What you are looking for is a background service that is always running. Unfortunately there is no direct way to make a background service in Ionic.

Why? Because your app is written in Javascript and your code runs in an Activity that has a webview. As soon as you exit your app, it is suspended.

This can be avoided by using ionic plugin [Ionic Native Background Mode](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/). This plugin helps your app stay open (in background) even if user closes it. So combining the background mode and pedometer, you could track steps even if app is closed (and pushed into background mode). But beware, this means that your app is technically still running, which means that in Android user will get a message that app is doing heavy tasks in the background. On iOS this usually results in the app getting rejected from app store.

Storing the steps: To store the steps you should use [Ionic Native Storage Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/). This persists the data even when the app is closed.

There is probably only one option for Android: Use Android background service, this can help keep apps open in the background as a service, doing only specific tasks.
iOS is a completely different problem: Apps can only run in background if they are using voip, audio, location, newstand. And even then they wont be completely free to do anything.

Hope this helps even though it's not good news.

Comment: Yea, I'll just go with the google fit and health kit solution, thanks anyways. :)